# Separate subnet with exceptions

Tags: networking, firewall, subnet

I have a network with clients in the 192.168.30.x range and clients in the 192.168.40.x range. both are in a 255.255.0.0 subnet.
All clients with .30.x are connected to one switch and all clients with .40.x connected to another switch and both switches are connected.
All clients with .30.x have a connection to the .40.x clients and vice versa.
Now we want to separate the network into two networks but need a exception. Two clients still need a connection. .30.10 must be able to connect to .40.1 (and .40.1 to .30.10)

How can we manage this, what would we need to get this working without changing anything on the clients ? It is possible, because of the same subnet ?

We have a [pc engines apu](http://www.pcengines.ch/apu.htm) with [ipfire](http://www.ipfire.org/) installed on it, is this maybe an option to achieve this ?

Comment: You need to change your subnet mask to /24 (255.255.255.0) and you need a router.

Comment: Before you play around with firewalls, please go and learn the basics about networking. Then come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: Daniel when i learned everything i don't need to ask questions. why didn't you give me the hot tip to use google ? useless comment..  

joeqwerty i can't change the subnet, that's my problem. with a router i know what to do, but i hoped to get this working on another way, there are so many solutions for networking problems, from vlan/pvlan to special hardware and many more.

Comment: Garog, I am sorry. I didn't see the part where you said that you cannot change the subnet so I assumed you don't know the basics. Could you maybe explain why you can't change them? Just so we understand your situation.

Comment: `i hoped to get this working on another way, there are so many solutions for networking problems, from vlan/pvlan to special hardware and many more` - VLAN's are a Layer 2 construct. Subnets are a Layer 3 construct. The only way to do what you need is to change the subnet mask and use a router.

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks to Daniel i now know that i can do this with a bridged firewall. i tried it with the linux from the ipfire on my APU and it's working wonderful. now you learned something too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something know as a transparent router, transparent firewall or bridged firewall.

Basically a firewall where you put two ports in bridge-mode, or "transparent" because the resulting ports will appear as switch-ports to connected computers. Frames are just sent through, but internally the firewall is able to react upon the packets contents. For example by dropping all packets from 192.168.40.0/24 to 192.168.30.0/24 except for that one computer.

I am not familiar with IPFire, but I assume that won't be a problem with that product.

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. A bridged Firewall and it was very easy to setup. Two ports into bridge mode and some iptables rules like
`iptables -P FORWARD DROP  
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -s 192.168.40.1 -d 192.168.30.10 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -s 192.168.30.10 -d 192.168.40.1 -j ACCEPT`  
and it worked as i hoped, thx a lot